# Regex url is not recognized

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex in the server side that checks if the url is valid:

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
```

This check is enough for me.

I want to make the same test in the client side.

So I created this jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/LZf7H/1830/
```

I can't make the regex to be recognized:

```
var regex = /http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?/i;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape forward slashes `/` as it will be considered as premature end of regular expression pattern for javascript.

```
var regex = /http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w- .\/?%&=]*)?/i;
```

---

Examples:

```
regex.test("http://test.com")
=> true

regex.test("http://www.test.com")
=> true

regex.test("http://abc.test.com")
=> true
```

Comment: the '?' in the sixth character doesnt say that http and https are not important? I dont understand why I got false for: www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all the forward slashes.

```
> var regex = /http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w- .\/?%&=]*)?/i;
> regex.test("http://myweb.com/api/v1/customer")
true
```

Comment: this is already there.Please check before posting same answers

Comment: @vks don't ask me like this. 2 or 4 sec differences is not a matter. I added some words but you posted only the regex.

Comment: @Blender right!!!!but i do delete my answers if i find d same posted before.Anywaz looks like that's not d policy anymore

Comment: @AvinashRaj and why do you think so?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R its not about reputation...its about decluttering SO

Answer (score 0):

```
/http(s)?:\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?/
```

Try this.Escape the `/`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/37